# Using a calculated field to pull x characters before a specific identifier Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a field, "ID" that is formatted as `###""-""##`. For example `545R-T67`. I have another field `"Name"` in the same table that pulls the information before the dash and creates it into its own field.

Right now the field is calculated to pull the first four characters `Left([ID],4)` the  Data edition requires the data to be formatted to include data with two letters after the three numbers.

I am wondering how I can update the field to pull all characters before the dash instead of just a set amount. Is there a function in Access that makes this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `LEFT` with `INSTR` to do this. `INSTR` returns the position of the character you're looking for (the dash).

```
Left([ID],INSTR([ID], "-"))
```

Note this will return everything before the first dash, but will return a zero-length string if there's no dash at all.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, however, I am getting a syntax error when using what you provided above. Could you help me locate the error?

Comment: Eh... This shouldn't cause a syntax error, so I don't really have a clue why it would without further information. Can you explain exactly what you're doing or provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Gustav I assume it's stored with the symbols included, as can be done with an input mask. That also doesn't explain the syntax error.

Comment: @ErikA I'm confused how I can get this to work if the dash isn't recognized. Do you have any advice?